# i am sending through jmeter the 50 users 90 % users getting successful and 10 % users i am getting failed

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, jmeter

i am sending the request  through JMeter   the 50 users 90 % users getting successful and 10 % users i am getting failed  i am getting the the error like ({"message":"Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'IMGDATA' in Error while blockUnblockAgentSlot"} and how to resolve the thise error

i am sending the 50 users 90 % users getting successful and 10 % users i am getting failed  i am getting the the error like ({"message":"Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'IMGDATA' in Error while blockUnblockAgentSlot"} and how to resolve the these error how to  resolve these issues

Comment: as every connection needs resources, you will hit a barrier, where you get failed from the server, inmysql it is best when there are problem to view the error log, this will usually tell you if something is wrong

Comment: You'll have to show the code responsible for the error if you want help with it

Comment: i am getting the Internal Server Error  how to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The [error description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/in_operator_no_object) says:

> The JavaScript exception "right-hand side of 'in' should be an object" occurs when the in operator was used to search in strings, or in numbers, or other primitive types. It can only be used to check if a property is in an object.

From your question it is not clear whether you're sending an incorrect request or your server incorrectly parses it.

If all 50 users send exactly the same request all the times it might be the case your application becomes overloaded and cannot handle that many. Try [increasing the load gradually](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period) to see up to what number of users the system under test behaves normally, how response times look like and so on.

If you're sending different requests with different users - it might indicate problem with parameterization, correlation or test data, you need to compare "problematic" requests with the "successful" ones and check how they are different. It cane be done using i.e. [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

In both cases it makes sense to look into the system under test logs, it should be way more information there.